# Recreating Keras model in numpy

Tags: python, keras, batch-normalization

I'm trying to take the trained weights from a keras model and trying to implement the forward model in numpy. Currently the results that I get are different to the outputs of my keras model.

I've narrowed the difference down to where I implement batch_normalisation. Just wondering what have I done wrong with my BN implementation below:

```
weights = model.get_weights()
h1_w = weights[0] #no bias term

h2_w, h2_b, bn2_gamma, bn2_beta, bn2_mean, bn2_var = weights[1:7]

def relu(x, w, b):
    return np.maximum(0, np.matmul(x, w) + b)

def bn(x, mean, var, gamma, beta, eps=1e-3):
    return (x-mean)/(np.sqrt(var) + eps)*gamma + beta

def reconstruct_model(x, x_offset):
    h1_act = np.maximum(0, np.matmul(x, h1_w))   
    h2_act = relu(h1_act, h2_w, h2_b)
    h2 = bn(h2_act, bn2_mean, bn2_var, bn2_gamma, bn2_beta)
    return h2
```

For comparison my Keras model is as follows:

```
x_in = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1:]))
h = Dense(20, use_bias=False, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(1e-5))(x_in)
h = Dense(10, activation='relu')(h)
out = BatchNormalization()(h)

model = Model([x_in], out)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

Also note that 1. I realise you don't put BN on the last layer. I've simply trimmed down to the first layer where I noticed discrepancies. 2. The difference is not due to float64 vs float32 problems (my biggest difference was around 0.6).

In summary, what's wrong with my BN implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't test the implementation in python but in c++. I put the `eps` inside the square root and my results are similar to the keras implementation by 10e-4 or better:

```
def bn(x, mean, var, gamma, beta, eps=1e-3):
    return (x-mean)/(np.sqrt(var + eps))*gamma + beta
```

Comment: Hmm ok. I'll test that out. But 1e-4 is a pretty decent gap to be honest.

Comment: The difference is overall in a network with several layers where errors propagate.